# Find the equation of the tangent line to $y=x^4-4x^3-5x+7$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equation of the tangent line to $y=x^4-4x^3-5x+7$ at the point (1,-1)

I'm completely at a lost for this problem. Am i going to use $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ formula?

Please Help!!!

Comment: Do you know how to take the derivative of a polynomial?

Comment: @IanColey do you mean like the derivative's rules?

Comment: Without using the awful limit formula, do you know the quick way to take the derivative of a polynomial via the power rule?

Comment: @IanColey Yes I know all of the rules for derivatives. So I'm going to the power rule for the $x$'s and the constant rule for the 7?

Comment: Yep. So what is $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: @IanColey it is $\frac{dy}{dx}=4x^3+12x^2-5$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10642/discussion-between-ian-coley-and-john-beal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a point that's on the line we desire, and also on the curve: the point $(1, -1)$.

We find the first derivative of the curve, and evaluate it at $x = 1$ (which we will use to obtain the *slope* of the line tangent to the curve at $(1, -1))$.

So, given $y=x^4-4x^3-5x+7$,  we have, by the power rule, that $$y'(x) = 4x^3 - 12x^2 - 5$$

and at $(1, -1)$, we use $x = 1$ and evaluate $y'(1):$ $$y'(1) = 4(1)^3 - 12(1)^2 - 5 = -13$$

So we have a point on the tangent line: $(x_0, y_0) = (1, -1)$ and the slope of the line tangent at that point: $m = -13.$

Now all that's left to obtain the equation of the tangent line is to use the point-slope form of an equation: $$y - y_0 = m(x- x_0)$$
$$\begin{align} y - (-1) & = -13(x - 1) \\ \\ \iff y + 1 & = -13x + 13 \\ \\ \iff 13x + y & = 12\end{align}$$

And you now have various ways to express the equation of line that is tangent to the curve at the point $(1, -1)$.

Comment: nice write - up +1